# Printing back and fourth

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

using namespace std;
void handlera(int signum){
    int main();

}
void handler(int signum){
    int i=0;
    signal(SIGINT, handlera);
    while(1){
        i++;
    cout<<"processing"<<i<<endl;
    sleep(2);
   }
   exit(signum);

}
int main()
{
   signal(SIGINT, handler);
   while(1){
       sleep(1);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Change printing back and fourth. Please help.

Comment: It behaves as expected: during signal handler the signal is blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but why don't you try something like:

```
int flag=0;
int i=0;
void handler(int signum){
   signal(SIGINT, handler);
   flag = 1-flag;
   i=0;
}

int main()
{
   signal(SIGINT, handler);
   while(1){
       if (flag==0){
           sleep(1);
       }else{ 
           i++;
           cout<<"processing"<<i<<endl;
           sleep(2);   
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

It is a better code design and should give the desired behavior...

Comment: Awesome ! This is definitely what I wanted as my result. I learned a lot from understanding your code. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`int main()` is a declaration, not a function call.

But you're not allowed to call `main()` anyway so, if you changed this to `main()`, your program would not compile:

> `error: ISO C++ forbids taking address of function '::main'`

I suggest refactoring your solution.